# memory leaks: Empty Android project + Dagger2 + LeakCanary

Tags: dagger-2

Faced such a problem. 
I create a new project with Empty Activity, and add the dependencies of the project, dagger2 and leakcanary. 
Run the application, then close and the leakcanary displays a memory leak.

Add dependencies

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
//Dagger
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1"
//Debug
debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4"
```

Create appkication class and init leakcanary

```
class AppDelegate: Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        onApplicationCreate()
        initDagger(this)
    }

    private fun initDagger(app: Application): AppComponent =
            DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                    .appModule(AppModule(app))
                    .dataModule(DataModule())
                    .build()

    private fun onApplicationCreate() {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            if (LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(this)) {
                return
            }
            LeakCanary.install(this)
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity class

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Create dagger component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class, DataModule::class))
interface AppComponent {
}

@Module
class AppModule(private val appContext: Application) {

    @Provides
    fun provideContext() = appContext
}

@Module
class DataModule {
}
```

Here is what leakcanary shows [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYJql.png)

If the dependence of the dagger2 is removed, then there is no leakage.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say what's happening. Leak canary reports that your main activity is being leaked, but I don't even see where it's being used. Do you pass it around? maybe as context?

Comment: The fact of the matter is that I do not transmit anywhere the context. The project is empty.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem, but didn't manage to. It's quite interesting. Do you have a sample project?

Comment: I posted a google disk https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vjOhVS8bx4PIvlcCxu73kb86mK6OYZgp/view

Comment: I can't get it to leak... Does it leak consistently for you? If so, what exactly are you doing? What's your setup - Android version, phone, etc?

Comment: I used Android 7.1.1. I tried on another version and everything is ok. Apparently the problem in the version of Android. I apologize for the time taken away

Comment: No need to apologize at all. I found it super interesting. Maybe you could answer your own question then?